# checkinstall / make does not work for the program razercfg that I wish to install

Tags: command-line, apt, make, checkinstall, autoconf

My goal is to change my mouse DPI. So any less frustrating solution is also welcome.

I've already searched and read through the other topics about `razercfg` & many others trying to figure out how to not get these errors but I'm new to Linux and even the answers I'm reading a just confusing me more.

I'm trying to install `razercfg` that can be found here: http://bues.ch/cms/hacking/razercfg.html

I've downloaded the tar.bz2 archive and extracted it into my home folder.

I've opened the readme and now I've been stuck at the start of the installation instructions for a few hours. I'm following the instructions of the README file located inside the archive.

I've already managed to get '**cmake .**' to work (I think) by changing into the directory through the terminal and running this command.

Output of cmake:

```
wico@wico-System-Product-Name ~/razerconfig $ cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.8.4
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Looking for libusb.h
-- Looking for libusb.h - found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/wico/razerconfig
wico@wico-System-Product-Name ~/razerconfig $
```

Now I'm running into trouble trying to run 'make' in the terminal.

The error I'm getting is:

```
make: *** No targets specified and no makefile found.  Stop.
```

I've tried make install:

```
make: *** No rule to make target `install'.  Stop.
```

I've come across some tip saying I should use autoconf:

```
autoconf: error: no input file
```

Somewhere else mentioned I should try ./configure

```
bash: ./configure: No such file or directory
```

I've also tried **checkinstall** among other things.
And I've read about dependencies being a possible solution.

I now managed to get a few steps further with the reply that i'll mark as the answer.

I was made aware of constantly expanding my question with more questions, so I've asked another question about the final part of the installation here:
[getting razercfg to work using systemd - systemctl: command not found](https://askubuntu.com/questions/638838/getting-razercfg-to-work-using-systemd-systemctl-command-not-found)

Comment: Is there a Makefile anywhere in your build directory?  The Makefile is being generated by cmake, so ensure it works and exits properly.

Comment: Like @the_Seppi says, this is most likely because the `cmake` step failed to complete successfully - perhaps because your system lacks the necessary prerequisites such as `libusb-1.0-0-dev`. Run `cmake .` again and this time examine its output carefully.

Comment: Also, you can add the output of cmake to this question as an [edit].

Comment: I've updated my question and i had installed libusb-1.0-0 already.

Comment: Why is your folder `razerconfig` and not `razercfg-0.32`. Did you specify a target directory for `tar xf …`?

Comment: I re-extracted it just now because i messed around too much with razercfg-0.32. But i've since pulled the folder from git that is just named 'razer' the way you provided in your answer.

Comment: Your problem is solved (cmake, make, checkinstall). Do not expand your question with new problems. If there are other problems, then you should ask a new question. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Follow the commands below, I tested all of these possibilities:*

```
git clone git://git.bues.ch/razer.git
cd razer
mkdir build
cd build
cmake ..
make
```

or

```
git clone git://git.bues.ch/razer.git
cd razer
cmake .
make
```

or

```
wget http://bues.ch/razercfg/razercfg-0.32.tar.bz2
tar xf razercfg-0.32.tar.bz2
cd razercfg-0.32
cmake .
make
```

---

*After that:*

```
sudo checkinstall
```

or **if there are dependency problems**

```
sudo make install
```

---

*Now follow the steps in `README`*

> If you use systemd:
>
> The `make install` step installed the razerd.service file. Reboot or
>   run the following command as root to start the razerd daemon:
>
> `systemctl start razerd`
>
> If you do NOT use systemd:
>
> To automatically start the required system daemon "razerd" at bootup
>   time, you need to install the init-script. This software package
>   includes a generic example script, that should work out-of-the-box on
>   many Linux distributions. To install it, invoke the following commands
>   as root:
>
> `cp ./razerd.initscript /etc/init.d/razerd`
>   `ln -s /etc/init.d/razerd /etc/rc2.d/S99razerd`
>   `ln -s /etc/init.d/razerd /etc/rc5.d/S99razerd`
>   `ln -s /etc/init.d/razerd /etc/rc0.d/K01razerd`
>   `ln -s /etc/init.d/razerd /etc/rc6.d/K01razerd`
>
> If you use udev:
>
> The `make install` step installed the udev script to
>   `$(pkg-config --variable=udevdir udev)/rules.d/80-razer.rules`
>   This should work on most distributions.
>
> If udev notification does not work, try to reboot the system.

---

*Example output `cmake .` and `make`*

```
[aboettger:~/tmp/razercfg-0.32] % cmake .
-- The C compiler identification is GNU 4.9.2
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc
-- Check for working C compiler: /usr/bin/cc -- works
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info
-- Detecting C compiler ABI info - done
-- Check if the system is big endian
-- Searching 16 bit integer
-- Looking for sys/types.h
-- Looking for sys/types.h - found
-- Looking for stdint.h
-- Looking for stdint.h - found
-- Looking for stddef.h
-- Looking for stddef.h - found
-- Check size of unsigned short
-- Check size of unsigned short - done
-- Using unsigned short
-- Check if the system is big endian - little endian
-- Looking for libusb.h
-- Looking for libusb.h - found
-- Configuring done
-- Generating done
-- Build files have been written to: /home/aboettger/tmp/razercfg-0.32

[aboettger:~/tmp/razercfg-0.32] % make
Scanning dependencies of target razer
[  5%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/buttonmapping.o
[ 10%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/profile_emulation.o
[ 15%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/librazer.o
[ 20%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/config.o
[ 25%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/util.o
[ 30%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/synapse.o
[ 35%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/cypress_bootloader.o
[ 40%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/hw_boomslangce.o
[ 45%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/hw_copperhead.o
[ 50%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/hw_deathadder.o
[ 55%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/hw_deathadder2013.o
[ 60%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/hw_deathadder_chroma.o
[ 65%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/hw_krait.o
[ 70%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/hw_lachesis.o
[ 75%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/hw_lachesis5k6.o
[ 80%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/hw_naga.o
[ 85%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/hw_imperator.o
[ 90%] Building C object librazer/CMakeFiles/razer.dir/hw_taipan.o
Linking C shared library librazer.so
[ 90%] Built target razer
Scanning dependencies of target razerd
[ 95%] Building C object razerd/CMakeFiles/razerd.dir/razerd.o
Linking C executable razerd
[ 95%] Built target razerd
Scanning dependencies of target pyrazer
[100%] Generating build/stamp
running build
running build_py
creating /home/aboettger/tmp/razercfg-0.32/ui/build
creating /home/aboettger/tmp/razercfg-0.32/ui/build/lib
creating /home/aboettger/tmp/razercfg-0.32/ui/build/lib/pyrazer
copying pyrazer/main.py -> /home/aboettger/tmp/razercfg-0.32/ui/build/lib/pyrazer
copying pyrazer/__init__.py -> /home/aboettger/tmp/razercfg-0.32/ui/build/lib/pyrazer
running build_scripts
creating /home/aboettger/tmp/razercfg-0.32/ui/build/scripts-3.4
copying and adjusting razercfg -> /home/aboettger/tmp/razercfg-0.32/ui/build/scripts-3.4
copying and adjusting qrazercfg -> /home/aboettger/tmp/razercfg-0.32/ui/build/scripts-3.4
changing mode of /home/aboettger/tmp/razercfg-0.32/ui/build/scripts-3.4/razercfg from 664 to 775
changing mode of /home/aboettger/tmp/razercfg-0.32/ui/build/scripts-3.4/qrazercfg from 664 to 775
[100%] Built target pyrazer
```

---

*Sample output `sudo checkinstall`*

```
[aboettger:~/tmp/razercfg-0.32] % sudo checkinstall

checkinstall 1.6.2, Copyright 2009 Felipe Eduardo Sanchez Diaz Duran
           This software is released under the GNU GPL.



*****************************************
**** Debian package creation selected ***
*****************************************

This package will be built according to these values: 

0 -  Maintainer: [ root@sturm ]
1 -  Summary: [ Package created with checkinstall 1.6.2 ]
2 -  Name:    [ razercfg ]
3 -  Version: [ 0.32 ]
4 -  Release: [ 1 ]
5 -  License: [ GPL ]
6 -  Group:   [ checkinstall ]
7 -  Architecture: [ amd64 ]
8 -  Source location: [ razercfg-0.32 ]
9 -  Alternate source location: [  ]
10 - Requires: [  ]
11 - Provides: [ razercfg ]
12 - Conflicts: [  ]
13 - Replaces: [  ]

Enter a number to change any of them or press ENTER to continue:

Installing with make install...

========================= Installation results ===========================
[ 90%] Built target razer
[ 95%] Built target razerd
[100%] Built target pyrazer
Install the project...
-- Install configuration: ""
-- Installing: /lib/udev/rules.d/80-razer.rules
-- udevadm control --reload-rules: 0
-- Installing: /etc/pm/sleep.d/50-razer
-- Installing: /lib/systemd/system/razerd.service
-- systemctl --system daemon-reload: 0
-- systemctl --system enable razerd.service: 0
-- Installing: /usr/local/lib/librazer.so
-- ldconfig: 0
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/razerd
-- Removed runtime path from "/usr/local/bin/razerd"
running install
running build
running build_py
running build_scripts
running install_lib
creating /usr/local/lib/python3.4
creating /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages
creating /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyrazer
copying build/lib/pyrazer/main.py -> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyrazer
copying build/lib/pyrazer/__init__.py -> /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyrazer
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyrazer/main.py to main.cpython-34.pyc
byte-compiling /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/pyrazer/__init__.py to __init__.cpython-34.pyc
running install_scripts
copying build/scripts-3.4/qrazercfg -> /usr/local/bin
copying build/scripts-3.4/razercfg -> /usr/local/bin
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/qrazercfg to 775
changing mode of /usr/local/bin/razercfg to 775
running install_egg_info
Writing /usr/local/lib/python3.4/dist-packages/razercfg-0.32-py3.4.egg-info
-- Installing: /usr/local/bin/razer-gamewrapper

======================== Installation successful ==========================

Copying documentation directory...
./
./README
./COPYING

Some of the files created by the installation are inside the home directory: /home

You probably don't want them to be included in the package.
Do you want me to list them?  [n]: 
Should I exclude them from the package? (Saying yes is a good idea)  [n]: 

Some of the files created by the installation are inside the build
directory: /home/aboettger/tmp/razercfg-0.32

You probably don't want them to be included in the package,
especially if they are inside your home directory.
Do you want me to list them?  [n]: 
Should I exclude them from the package? (Saying yes is a good idea)  [y]: 

Copying files to the temporary directory...OK

Stripping ELF binaries and libraries...OK

Compressing man pages...OK

Building file list...OK

Building Debian package...OK

Installing Debian package...OK

Erasing temporary files...OK

Writing backup package...OK
OK

Deleting temp dir...OK


**********************************************************************

 Done. The new package has been installed and saved to

 /home/aboettger/tmp/razercfg-0.32/razercfg_0.32-1_amd64.deb

 You can remove it from your system anytime using: 

      dpkg -r razercfg

**********************************************************************
```

Comment: Your answer seems to have helped and i do get similar output but does this mean it's fully working now or do i need to continue the README-instructions from a certain point onward to get the GUI to work, because i have no way of testing whether i did it right.

Comment: Simply start `sudo checkinstall`

Comment: I've updated my question with the current progress and i seem to be stuck at 'sudo checkinstall' now, as it seems to have crashed my terminal unless that's how checkinstall is supposed to end.

Comment: I've managed to get checkinstall to work now and have updated my question.

Comment: Were you satisfied with my answer? Then give me an upvote (∧). If I could solve your problem, then it would be nice if you'd mark my answer (✓). http://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers ;)

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install systemd-services`

Comment: You've helped me a lot but i'm unsure whether i should mark your answer as i just run into problem after problem with each new step of the README-instructions. And anyone that'll look to this question in the future still won't be able to get it working. So I can mark your answer but i'll just give up trying to fix this as it's already taken me a day and knowing that on windows i can get all this working in under 30 seconds (and more).

Comment: This is exactly why you should not continue to expand your question.

Comment: Question 1:  How do I compile?, Q2:  How do I install, Q3: The program needs systemd.

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get install systemd-services`  and `make install` if `sudo checkinstall` doesn't work.

Comment: I've cleaned up my question and have marked your answer. Thank you for your time.